# Add elements to a dynamic array with array_push

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have this array `file_months` that changes when an new month it adds to a folder:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
)
```

What I want is to display all the months in a select option, so I tried this :

```
$nbr_mois = array('0'=>'01','1'=>'02','2'=>'03','3'=>'04','4'=>'05','5'=>'06','6'=>'07','7'=>'08','8'=>'09','9'=>'10','10'=>'11','11'=>'12');
foreach ($nbr_mois as $key => $value) {
    if($value!=$file_months)
array_push($file_months,$value);
}
```

but it doesn't add a missing months, it adds them all! Like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 01
    [4] => 02
    [5] => 03
    [6] => 04
    [7] => 05
    [8] => 06
    [9] => 07
    [10] => 08
    [11] => 09
    [12] => 10
    [13] => 11
    [14] => 12
)
```

Comment: Can't you just do `$file_months = $nbr_mois`?

Comment: +1 because I had to change my shorts after I read this!

Comment: You are comparing a value to an array. Use the `array_search` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think `array_merge` will work for you without the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the key exists already

```
$nbr_mois = array('0'=>'01','1'=>'02','2'=>'03','3'=>'04','4'=>'05','5'=>'06','6'=>'07','7'=>'08','8'=>'09','9'=>'10','10'=>'11','11'=>'12');
foreach ($nbr_mois as $key => $value) {
if(!array_key_exists($key, $arrayname) {
    if($value!=$file_months)
        array_push($file_months,$value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just replace

```
if($value!=$file_months)
    array_push($file_months,$value);
```

with

```
if($value!=$file_months[$key])
    $file_months[$key] = $value;
```

Comment: Good point. The OP didn't say if he wanted to append only nonexistant values, or he wanted them overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

use `in_array`..

Instead of

```
if($value!=$file_months) {

}
```

Use this..

```
if(!in_array($value,$file_months)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in_array() method as shown below:

```
if(!in_array($value, $file_months))
```

instead of

```
if($value!=$file_months)
```